# How to refer to a text after extracting from spaCy Match?

Tags: python, nlp, pattern-matching

I use spaCy match to extract the keywords.

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab, validate=True)

patterns = [{"LOWER": "self"}, {'IS_PUNCT': True, 'OP':'*'}, {"LOWER": "employed"}]
patterns1 = [{'LOWER': 'finance'}]
patterns2 = [{'LOWER': 'accounting'}]
    
matcher.add("Experience", None, patterns)
matcher.add("CFA", None, patterns1)
matcher.add("CPA", None, patterns2)
    
text = """ I am a self employed working in a remote factory. However, I study finance and accounting by myself in
my spare time."""

doc = nlp(text)
matches = matcher(doc)
```

Later, I create a dataframe containing all keywords:

```
L=[]
M=[]
for match_id, start, end in matches:
        rule_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]  # get the unicode ID, i.e. 'CategoryID'
        span = doc[start : end]  # get the matched slice of the doc
        L.append(rule_id)
        M.append(span.text)

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Keywords': L,
     'Profession': M,})
print(df)

#Output
     Keywords     Profession
0  Experience  self employed
1         CFA        finance
2         CPA     accounting
```

Then I want to build a subset dataframe when profession is self employed.

```
#Output
     Keywords     Profession
0  Experience  self employed
```

If I do it with hard-coding, I will have to adjust it every time depending on the test extracted. For example, the text could be self-employed, self employed, Self Employed, and others.

I appreciate any ideas. Thank you

Comment: What have you tried (could you update your question to share some code) ? I don't quite understand what the problem is exactly. Could you show what output you expect ?

Comment: I improve my question. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

In your case making `IS_PUNCT` optional should do it:

`patterns = [{"LOWER": "self"}, {'IS_PUNCT': True, 'OP':'?'}, {"LOWER": "employed"}]`

I'm still not sure if I know, what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to always have to save "self employed" when your pattern matches? If so, here's a possible solution:

```
for match_id, start, end in matches:
        rule_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]  # get the unicode ID, i.e. 'CategoryID'
        span = doc[start : end]  # get the matched slice of the doc
        exp_span = span.text
        if rule_id == "Experience":
            exp_span = "self employed"
        L.append(rule_id)
        M.append(exp_span)
```

Comment: It is not what I exactly need. I will improve my question. Thank you

Comment: I'm trying to help but still unsure if I understand

Comment: Thank you. in the exp_span="self employed", you hardcoded self employed. In the pattern, the text extracted could be self-employed. So you have to modify your hard coding. My question is if I can do something else so I do not need to hardcode it. Do you understand?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm completely lost. I have no idea, what you are really trying to do. In your code, you don't hard-code it, you will save self-employed just as it is.

Comment: When I create the subset, I have to say to choose the subset when Profession = 'self employed'. That is hardcoded. In reality, it depends on the text extracted.